# Qt: receive serial port data as unsigned char

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

with my main app I'm sending bytes and I'm sending them as unsigned chars (0x80 and above). I created one small supporting app that receives these data, writes them to terminal and then sends them back as a confirmation of successful transfer. But with this code in support app:

```
switch(c) // c being byte from received QByteArray
{
case 0xFF: cout << "Header 1" << endl;
    break;
case -1: cout << "0xFF = 255 = -1" << endl;
    break;
}  //other case statements and default omitted
```

if I send 0xFF through serial port, I get "0xFF = 255 = -1" on cout. 
I do understand that this number is represented by 1111 1111 (and that in fact 255 equals -1 in this case) thanks to another post here on SOF. But how am I supposed to receive the code to get "Header 1" on the terminal?

Comment: You will need to convert the numbers to a textual representation before output:  `cout << hex << ((uint8_t)c) << endl;`

Comment: Also too, with GCC 4.9, without the cast in the switch statement you will get: warning: case label value exceeds maximum value for type for the case 0xFF, with the cast the warning moves to your case -1 which I suppose is only there for debugging. Essentially what this warning is telling you is that the compiler is ignoring the out of bounds label and not producing any code for it at all.